# How to change a variable 2 times using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to change a variable using sed, but its kinda different (for me, at least) so I couldn't find any answers online.

Here's basically what I'm trying to do;

```
sed -i '"/${_variable}"=0/c\"${_variable}=1"' ${_conf}
```

so in config file, there is a variable;

```
_variable=test
```

and the present file has this line;

```
${_variable}=0
```

so the variable changes to;

```
test=0
```

and I want to change this `test=0` to `test=1` but the text `test` is not a static content, it fetches its content from `${_variable}`.

So how can I change this with sed?

Comment: Wouldn't that be something like `sed "s/${_variable}=0/${_variable}=1/"`?

Comment: you just saved my day! thank you so much! it was just needed a little addition, which is; `sed -I` instead of `sed` thats it! thank you so much again

Comment: @melpomene, Please post that as an answer.